# How to fetch the current target (or currently clicked) UI Element using puppeteer and NodeJS API

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I am new to using puppeteer and chrome-dev-tools API. I am trying to fetch the currently clicked element i.e. event.Target from browser context to Node/Puppeteer instance so i could convert the same to a JSON for usage later. I have tried below methods but none of them seem to serve as a solution to my problem statement.

Approach 1:
I tried to fetch the element using a combination of page.exposeFunction() and page.evaluate() functions but the value printed into node console seems like some other window sub-object instead of a WebElement however the browser console is able to print this value perfectly fine as a Webelement

```
const pptr = require('puppeteer-core');
const EventEmitter = require("events");
const myEventTracker = new EventEmitter();

const runScript = async function(){

    const browser = await pptr.launch({
        headless:false,
        executablePath:'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe',
    });

    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('<APPLICATION URL>');
    await page.evaluate(async function(){
        document.addEventListener('click',async function(e){
            fetchElement(e.target);
        })
    })

    await page.exposeFunction('fetchElement',async function(args){
        console.log(await args);
    })

    myEventTracker.on(Event,function(e){
        console.log(e);
    })
}

runScript();
```

In the above approach the output printed by fetchElement() is as below:

```
{ __zone_symbol__ngModelChangefalse:
   [ { type: 'eventTask',
       state: 'scheduled',
       source: 'HTMLInputElement.addEventListener:ngModelChange',
       zone: 'angular',
       runCount: 0 } ],
  __zone_symbol__keydownfalse:
   [ { type: 'eventTask',
       state: 'scheduled',
       source: 'HTMLInputElement.addEventListener:keydown',
       zone: '<root>',
       runCount: 0 } ],
  __zone_symbol__inputfalse:
   [ { type: 'eventTask',
       state: 'scheduled',
       source: 'HTMLInputElement.addEventListener:input',
       zone: 'angular',
       runCount: 0 } ],
  __zone_symbol__blurfalse:
   [ { type: 'eventTask',
       state: 'scheduled',
       source: 'HTMLInputElement.addEventListener:blur',
       zone: 'angular',
       runCount: 0 } ],
  __zone_symbol__compositionstartfalse:
   [ { type: 'eventTask',
       state: 'scheduled',
       source: 'HTMLInputElement.addEventListener:compositionstart',
       zone: 'angular',
       runCount: 0 } ],
  __zone_symbol__compositionendfalse:
   [ { type: 'eventTask',
       state: 'scheduled',
       source: 'HTMLInputElement.addEventListener:compositionend',
       zone: 'angular',
       runCount: 0 } ] }
```

Instead of below which is perfectly printed in browser's console:

```
<h4 id="the-observer-pattern-for-our-event-emitter">The Observer Pattern for Our Event Emitter</h4>
```

Approach 2:

The second approach i tried to use EventEmiter but no luck in using the same as well as i get an unhandled promise rejection no matter what i do.

Please help/suggest any other method by which i can fetch a target/clicked WebElement from a live chrome instance. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I believe the issue is, that puppeteer doesn't know how to serialize a DOM node. What do you want to do with the node/JSON information afterwards?

Comment: I want to store the webelements to use them later for automation.

Comment: try using `e.target.innerHTML` or building your own serialization iterating through the nodes of e.target and put it into a simple object for `fetchElement`